# How to retrieve data via HTTP without using promises

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, observable, ionic4

I have the following service code I simplified for posting here

```
    Load(Channel: any) {
        // 
        let URL = Globals.AppSiteRoot + Channel.URL
        return this.LoadData(URL)
    }

    Load_Default() {
        let URL = Globals.AppSiteRoot + "dir1/somedata.XML"
        console.log("XYZService.Load_Default------.------>>URL", URL)
        //
        return this.LoadData(URL)
            .then(data => {
                {
                    // do some processing here
                    console.log("XYZService.Load_Default<<P------.------data", data)
                    console.log("XYZService.Load_Default<<P------.------This.Data", this.Data)
                }
            });
    }

    // https://medium.com/@balramchavan/using-async-await-feature-in-angular-587dd56fdc77
    // https://v5.angular.io/api
    // https://v5.angular.io/guide/comparing-observables
    LoadData(URL: string) {  // : Observable<any>

        return new Promise(resolve => {
            // first argument is URL, put config as second argument
            // return this.http.get(URL, {responseType: 'text'})
            this.HttpClient.get(URL)
                .map(res => res)
                .subscribe(
                    data => {
                        // 
                        console.log("XYZService.LoadData<<P------.------http.get=>data", data)
                        // Do some processing here, if needed...
                        this.Data = data
                        // return new Observable(this.Data);  
                        resolve(this.Data)
                    }
                    ,
                    err => {
                        // https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/handle-errors-with-http-services/53229
                        console.log("XYZService.LoadData<<P------.------http:ERR", err)
                    }
                );
        });
    }
```

In a XYZcomponent I do the following:

```
Show(Channel: any) {
        console.log("XYZComponent.Show------.------>>Channel>>" + Channel.URL)
        //
        this.XYZService.Load(Channel)
            .then(data => {
                console.log("XYZComponent.Show------.------>>data", data)  
                this.NavController.parent.select(1);
            });            
    }
```

If I switch to using **async/await** my component code becomes like this, which I must admit that once one accepts await is blocking, the code seems cleaner than the use of Promise .then....

```
    async ShowV2(Channel: any) {
        console.log("XYZComponent.Show------.------>>Channel>>" + Channel.URL)
        //
        const data = await this.XYZService.Load(Channel)
        console.log("XYZComponent------.------>>data", data)
        // 
        this.NavController.parent.select(1)
    }
```

I am getting mixed messages from the many posts and blogs I read.

Some say don't use HttpClient.get.subscribe if you expect to only receive data once..., instead use .toPromise() however they never show how to handle errors.

Some say async/await are only sugar syntax still using Promises under the hood.

Some say Observables are much better and even Angular uses them extensively.

Regarding the code in .Load() .Load_Default() and the component .Show() methods are these places to expect an Observables and how to code it as such?

I have used ReplaySubject(1) elsewhere to broadcast events from services and to communicate indirectly from page to page.  However, I am not sure this is another place to use it though.

My typical concern with event emitters like ReplaySubject(1), especially when I visit the code some months later,

1) How did I ensure I subscribed to an event only once? where?

2) Did I unsubscribe and where?

BTW, even though I am using Promises, Observables, ReplaySubject(1) it's all Chinese to me and a great source of distraction and frustration to get to my simple goal that of display some data or some pictures I retrieve from the web.
Therefor, if you have an approach/pattern to lay down the code clearly such that when I comeback four months from now, it all make sense :)

Please include template code with error handling you would use in production.
Thank you for sharing any of your insights.

```
npm show ionic version
5.4.16
npm show cordova version
9.0.0
npm show angular version
1.7.9
show @angular/core version
9.0.6
ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 9.0.4
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 5.0.3
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms, http
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.900.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.0.35
@angular-devkit/core              9.0.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.0.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular               9.0.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/update                0.900.4 (cli-only)
rxjs                              5.5.2
typescript                        2.8.3
webpack                           3.12.0
```

Comment: If you're using Angular you should be using Observables: it is indeed a cornerstone part of the framework. Your question is too broad and opinion based for a real answer. 1 thing: unsubscribing from HTTP calls is not required, they complete after their response.

Comment: Your question kind of rambles across a lot of topics and a lot of things you seem to be unsure of.  Can you boil it down to one or two clear questions you want help with?  FYI, `async/await` rely on promises.  They only work if your asynchronous operation is promise-based.  So, `async/await` are just a different syntax for using promises which can sometimes make the code simpler to write/understand.  You don't use `async/await` instead of promises.  You use `async/await` instead of `.then()` and you use `try/catch` around `async/await` instead of `.catch()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using Observables instead of Promises since Angular use the first a lot and in a way promotes the reactive style.

Consider the following example code:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SomeService {
  private readonly URL: string = 'someurl';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public loadData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.URL).pipe(
      // if you want to handle errors you can use the catchError operator
      // however, a better way is to use a HTTP Interceptor instead
      // if you want to see how you can handle errors with the interceptor let me 
      // know
      catchError(error => throwError(error)),
      map(res => // do some transformation if you need),
      tap(res => // add some side effects if you need)

     // don't subscribe in the service - it is considered to be a bad practice
  }
}
```

You can call the method in your component and manually subscribe to it or you can use the `async` pipe in the template to subscribe and unsubscribe automatically.

Although it's very important to unsubscribe from observables in to order to avoid memory leaks, Angular manages for you this for the HttpClient so is no need for you to manually unsubscribe.

For all other Observables you can use operators like `take`, `first`, `last`, `takeUntil` or store the subscription into a property of type `Subscription` and unsubscribe in the OnDestroy life cycle hook (the same must be done in the case of `takeUntil` operator where you call next and complete/unsubscribe for its argument which is a `Subject`).

If you want to use Promises instead, for handling errors you can use the `trycatch` block.

I've created a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbfarw) where I included the error interceptor.

Make sure to provide the interceptor in the providers array from the app module like so:

```
providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true }],
```

Comment: Thanks for providing code, could you please augment your answer with sample code on how you would invoke .loadData() now returning an Observable from a component and how you would handle errors at that level given that services are not expected to interact with the GUI/User.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes please show how to use this http interceptor. I am having difficulty with VSCode/TS accepting catchError and tap? map exists if I use .map
Perhaps you can show your sample at a site like this one.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqalu1
Thanks.

Comment: See the updated answer for the stackblitz. You can catch the error in the service and trigger an alert or a snak-bar with the error message. Regarding the use of the operators, what version of Angular are you using?

Comment: I am afraid I am not be seeing what you did, it's the first time I use stackblitz and I may have been overwriting what you were editing.  I think you have to click the "Fork" button and send me a unique link to your edits.
From my package.json I am using Angular still at 5.0.3 because I am stuck at ionic3 or 4, they keep changing and it's not easy for me to grasp the breaking changes. the stackblitz is using Angular 8 . I have appended to the post the versions of my development configuration.

Comment: If you can demonstrate thru stackblitz how you read a cross-domain resource like this https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml and display it to the console that would be fantastic.  Thank you so much for your guidance.

Comment: Ok, I see the correct link in your answer, it looks like interceptor is some short of app-level handler for all http transactions. I will need to study the code further and may be use it.  For now, I will be moving my .subscribe(s) out of services and much like my use of ReplaySubject subscribe on the consumers side like components (listeners).

Comment: Because you're using old versions of Angular and RxJS then you can't use pipeable operators like in the example. In RxJS, starting with v6, some operators have also been renamed. For example, in v6 the ```tap``` operator is ```do``` in v5. You can see in this gist how you can use the operators in RxJS v5: https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35