# catch Http error other than resolve/reject promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, error-handling, promise

All,

i am calling an API(back end) using promises in angular 8 typescript.
need to be able to get the error response back, how ever when i reject the error to get the response/error, I get "OK"(msg = "OK"), but in console i have the 500 error with the actual response.
see code and the response in network tab below.:

```
getAllItem(id: number) {
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.http.post<any>(environment.apiEndPoint,
    { "Method": "myMethod"},
    Helper.getHeader()).toPromise().then((res: any) => {
      resolve(res);
    },
      msg => { reject(msg); });
});
return promise;
```

}

this is my actual response in network tab:

```
{"Success": false, "ErrorCode": "SYSTEM909", "Data": {}}
```

in the network tab i get below
Status Code: 500

Thanks

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/60731896/11881804 will help you although it's using observables over promises.

Comment: no , i have just tried with chris's answer, no luck so far

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible that you have set interceptor which might changing the error. Please check the interceptor if you set or not.

Comment: spot on, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

you can use RxJS `catchError` instead

```js
getAllItem(id: number) {
  return this.http.post(environment.apiEndPoint).pipe(
    catchError(error => { ... }) // will catch 500 error from api call
  )
}
```

Comment: no, same again. I get "OK" in the catchError(error). however the response is something else.

Comment: So you're saying that the api is returning a 500 error with the body `{"Success": false, "ErrorCode": "SYSTEM909", "Data": {}}`, but the code above has the error variable inside the catchError equal to what?

Comment: the api is returning a 500 error with the response of {"Success": false, "ErrorCode": "SYSTEM909", "Data": {}} and the caterror returns "OK"

Comment: just the string "OK"? That doesn't really make sense.. and you removed all the other code trying to read from the header?

Comment: this is the code:    `    var obj = this.http.post<any>(apiendpoint,
      Helper.getHeader()).pipe(
        map(n => {
          console.log(n);
        }),
        catchError(error => of
          (console.log("catching error" + error))
        ));

    return obj; ` this returns text "OK"